# Move all files from all subfolders to new destination with grupping them by specific number of files per group in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following code to copy all files including those in subfolders from it's root folder to new destination, but I need to separate them into groups and keep the original folder structure.

When i run it, I'll get an error saying that the specified path, file name, or both are too long. It looks like it merges filenames and it's paths together or something like that. I can't figure out how to fix it.

What am I doing wrong?

```
# Get List Of All Files
$FileList1 = gci $path -recurse

# Remove Last Slash From The Path
$pathnoslash =  $path.Substring(0,$path.Length-1)

# Add Escape Slash To The Path For Regex
$regexpath = $pathnoslash -replace "\\", "\\"

# Move All Files From All Folders
For($i=1;$i -le [Math]::Ceiling(($FileList1.count)/$NumberOfFilesPerFolder);$i++){
    # Get Directory Names
    $newpath = (gci $path -recurse).DirectoryName |

    # Replace Source Root Folder By Destination Root Folder
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "$regexpath", "c:\ZIPPINGFOLDER\$i" }

    # Move Files Form Source To Destination
    gci $path -recurse -File | Select-Object -First $NumberOfFilesPerFolder |
    %{$_.moveto("$newpath\$($_.name)")}
}
```

Comment: `$_.moveto("$newpath\ `  - $newPath is an array, something like `"c:\zippingfolder\1","c:\zippingfolder\1","c:\zippingfolder\1"` on and on for as many *files* as there are in your original path. And putting it in the string in `moveto` just joins it up into one enormous string full of repeating paths. `What am I doing wrong?` - I dunno exactly, mashing random code together and crossing your fingers? I can't imagine this code doing anything like what you want it to do.

Comment: Well thanks for pointing out what's wrong, do you also have a solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
$NumberOfFilesPerFolder = 2
$newbase = 'c:\temp\zippingfolder'
$path = 'c:\temp\new'
$files = dir $path -Recurse -File
$pathnoslash = $path.TrimEnd('\')
$regexpath = [regex]::Escape($pathnoslash)

$filecount = 0
$foldernum = 0
foreach ($file in $files) {
    if (!($filecount % $NumberOfFilesPerFolder)) {
        $foldernum++
    }
    $filecount++

    $destdir = Join-Path $newbase $foldernum

    if (!(Test-Path $destdir)) {
        $null = md $destdir -Force
    }

    # if the file.txt already exists, rename it to file-1.txt and so on
    $num = 1
    $base = $file.basename
    $ext = $file.extension
    $newname = Join-Path $destdir "$base$ext"
    while (Test-Path $newname) {
        $newname = Join-Path $destdir "$base-$num$ext"
        $num++
    }

    move $file.fullname $newname
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony, i tried your code and it didn't create any folder structure in new destinations, all files were moved to the root of new group folders.

Comment: can you better explain what you are wanting to do? can you give a sample of what you have, example of what your code is doing that you don't want it to do, and and example of your desired result? also, please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve